# batch ERRORLEVEL problems

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-xp

I have a file that checks to see if a process is running. If so then it loops, if not it echoes a line into a txt file, My problem is that when the process isn't running it still continues the loop. Here's my code

```
:a
Tasklist /v | findstr CMD.exe | findstr LAN 
If ERRORLEVEL==1 goto :done
Goto :a

:done

Echo %USERNAME% has logged out. >>log.txt
```

I think I've done something wrong with ERRORLEVEL althought I've tried it with the if and if not statements with errorlevels of 0-2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot make compare operations with errorlevel like that.Try this:

```
If ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :done
```

or

```
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto :done
```

or

```
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto : done
```

And when you use FIND or FINDSTR you need quotes:

```
Tasklist /v | findstr "CMD.exe" | findstr "LAN"
```

You can also use conditional execution :

```
Tasklist /v | find "CMD.exe" | find "LAN" || goto :done
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue could be that CMD.exe is a case sensitive test and it wasn't being passed through the filter.  The /i switch will make the two findstr tests case insensitive.

Try this:  It will branch to :a if cmd.exe and lan are not found.

```
:a
Tasklist /v | findstr /i "CMD.exe" | findstr /i "LAN" >nul
If ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :a

Echo %USERNAME% has logged out. >>log.txt
```